# Get values from each json object of specific key

Tags: php, json, laravel

In my one project i required to extract each `phone` from input json. Json input something like:

```
[
      {
          "name": "Niyo",
        "email": "niyo@ymail.com",
        "phone": "8989457845"
      },
      {
          "name": "Picks",
        "email": "picks.p@gmail.com",
        "phone": "7878121245"
      },
      {
          "name": "Chintz",
        "email": "Chintz@gmail.com",
        "phone": "8745421254"
      },
      {
          "name": "Kabiru Wabyu",
        "email": "kabiru.v@gmail.com",
        "phone": ""
      },
      {
          "name": "Rons",
        "email": "",
        "phone": "9898989898"
      }
]
```

I know one solutions to extract each phone from input json `contact`

`foreach($contacts as $phone){
     $phones[]=$phone->phone;
}`

Is there any alternate way in php/laravel to get all values from input json for specific key ?

Comment: y r u not using json_decode()?

Comment: array_column may be what you need.  You must have PHP 5.5 or more recent tho.

Comment: @devpro he must be otherwise the foreach would not work

Comment: See [The manual for `array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) Its a great little resource for programmers, the manual that is

Comment: Yes.. array_column is solutions for me. Craig have answered

Comment: @Chintan7027: Hii..here i provide link [https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/] that useful in many things and also useful for this question. I know below answer's already solved your issue. Please go through it, might be helpful.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return what you're seeking, provided that you have PHP 5.5 or more recent.  Not sure if it's necessary to set the second parameter of json_decode to TRUE, which returns an array of arrays, rather than an array of objects.

```
$x = json_decode(yourjson, TRUE);
$phones = array_column($x, 'phone');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have this as an array, you can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/en/array_map)

```
$phones = array_map(function($contact) { return $contact->phone; }, $contacts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel helper functions:

```
$phones = array_pluck($contacts, 'phone');
```

or a Collection:

```
$contacts = collect($contacts);
$phones = $contacts->pluck('phone');
```

and don't forget to parse the JSON as an array:

```
$contacts = json_decode($json, true);
```